# perfect continuous conditional tense doubt

Tags: tenses, present-tense, continuous-aspect

"I just wanted for you to come back home when you would have been ready."

I wonder if the sentence above is correct. I have some doubts about the tense after "when".

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You are not using an "if" sentence, so the answer is indeed "I just wanted you to come back home when you were ready." The addition of "if" would change the tense and make the meaning different. For example: "I would have wanted you to come home if you had been ready."

Comment: My sentence, in the present form, would be "I just want you to come back when you will be ready". So translated into the past becomes:
"I just wanted you to come back when you were ready" ? It feels off to me. "were ready" sounds like the past translation of "are ready".

Answer (score 0):

"I just wanted you to come back home when you were ready."

Comment: I am referring to a situation in the past. Using an if sentence, it would be something like:
You would have come home if you had been ready.

So shouldn't your sentence be like:
"I just wanted you to come back home when you had been ready." Or 
"I just wanted you to come back home when you would have been ready."

Comment: No, because your sentence isn't actually conditional (your second example is). "You would have home if you had been ready" is actually "If you had been ready, you would have come home"--a conditional. But (stripping out extraneous words) "I wanted you to come home when you were ready" isn't conditional, it's subjunctive ("I wish you had come home when you were ready").

Comment: Here's another example from https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/82158-Subjunctive-vs-conditional:

Comment: There is a link between the conditional and subjunctive: in an unreal present conditional statement (one hypothetical or contrary to fact), the main clause (the result) is in the conditional while the subordinate clause (the condition) is in the subjunctive:

I would have more fun in Berlin if I spoke German. (I don't speak German).